# How to custom code for magento as developer

Tags: magento2

1. What is best IDE to develop code for magento?
2. we have admin panel and frontend. When we say we develop/custom magento, we just develop the functions for admin panel? instead of frontend? We use admin panel to control what it will be looked like in frontend? Can we directly develop code for frontend?
3. Is there any documentation to describe what is the code/project file structure for magento CE 2.1.5? I am new to it, I have no idea where to start to develop it?
4. If a magento in not 2.x.x version, we have to upgrade it to 2.x.x version for better security issue?
5. Can we debug step by step for magento? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is not "best: IDE, I am using Sublime3 now. So far it is really comfortable to me.
2. Develop magento is not just front-end or admin. It can be both or some thing not showing up in both. Like some database processor.
3. There are a lot of documents about magento, http://devdocs.magento.com/ this is the official one.
4. Up to date normally is a good idea, but some time you have you own situation that may be stay in some version would be better for specific situation.
5. JS you can use firebug or chrome developer tool to run step by step, and the server side code, you may not able to do that.

Comment: 5. The Firebug extension isn't being developed or maintained any longer

Comment: 5. What cannot step through PHP code like C# or Java? If we cannot, how can we find the reason for bugs in PHP?

Comment: Firebug is still powerful, it does not matter pick which developer tool you like. There are some basic error log from magento source/var/log/system.log(exception.log,system.log,debug.log). You can log out the value you want to check via debug.log by use code:     \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug();

Comment: There are some IDE seems can allow you to step through the code like Visual Studio Code.